# Serialize and deserialize binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree, serialization

Here is my code of serialize and de-serialize a binary tree, looking for advice. One issue in my mind which I cannot resolve is, I am using a global variable index, wondering if more elegant solutions in Python 2.7 -- since in Python there is no solution to pass a reference as Java/C++ did.

```
index = 0
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    @staticmethod
    def serialize(root, output):
        if not root:
            output.append('#')
            return
        output.append(root.value)
        Node.serialize(root.left, output)
        Node.serialize(root.right, output)
        return output
    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(source):
        global index
        if source[index] == '#':
            index += 1
            return None
        value = source[index]
        index += 1
        left = Node.deserialize(source)
        right = Node.deserialize(source)
        return Node(value, left, right)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Node('a', Node('b', None, None), Node('c', Node('e', Node('g', None, None), None), Node('f', None, None)))
    result = []
    Node.serialize(root, result)
    print result
    new_root = Node.deserialize(result)
    result2 = []
    Node.serialize(new_root, result2)
    print result2
```

Comment: "_since in Python there is no solution to pass a reference_". Where did you read this ?

Comment: You can use class attribute for storing index that which is also sort of global variable, but at least it's stored under class namespace.

Comment: @Alex, sounds good idea. If you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people. Also wondering if possible to do BFS other than DFS for serialize/deserialize?

Comment: @Dex'ter, could you show me how to pass int in Python by reference? Tried to search something failed.

Answer (score 3):

For starter, you don't need to use a global index. Python tuples make it easy to return several values at once, you can return the new index with the deserialized value:

```
    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(source):
        def _helper(index):
            if source[index] == '#':
                return None, index + 1

            value = source[index]
            left, index = _helper(index + 1)
            right, index = _helper(index)
            return Node(value, left, right), index
        return _helper(0)[0]
```

Now, what if I what to serialize the node `Node('#', None, None)`? I will get `['#', '#', '#']` as `output` that will get deserialized as `None`. Not that ideal. If you want to keep this intermediate format, you should at least allow the user to chose its sentinel value. Using a parameter with a default value in both `serialize` and `deserialize is a good option.

I would also improve the interface of your class: turning `serialize` into a method and `deserialize` into a `classmethod`. This allow for ease of use and easy subclassing:

```
class Node(object):
    ...

    def serialize(self, sentinel='#'):
        serial = [self.value]
        if self.left is None:
            serial.append(sentinel)
        else:
            serial.extend(self.left.serialize(sentinel))
        if self.right is None:
            serial.append(sentinel)
        else:
            serial.extend(self.right.serializr(sentinel))
        return serial

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, source, sentinel='#'):
        def _helper(index):
            if source[index] == sentinel:
                return None, index + 1

            value = source[index]
            left, index = _helper(index + 1)
            right, index = _helper(index)
            return cls(value, left, right), index
        return _helper(0)[0]
```

And at the very last, I would provide default values for the `left` and `right` parameters:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

So I can more easily write trees:

```
t = Node(13, Node(8), Node(15, right=Node(18)))
t.serialize()
# [13, 8, '#', '#', 15, '#', 18, '#', '#']
```

---

An other way to look at the problem is to take inspiration from `repr`. If we were to write an official representation for such objects, we could end up with:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}(value={!r}, left={!r}, right={!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.value, self.left, self.right)
```

And `repr(t)` would be the string:

```
Node(value=13, left=Node(value=8, left=None, right=None), right=Node(value=15, left=None, right=Node(value=18, left=None, right=None)))
```

It's a bit verbose, but it is serialized as a string. Using `eval` on this string would even deserialize it and return a `Node` equivalent to `t`. I however advise against the use of `eval` for deserialization purposes as it is too generic and thus dangerous.

Instead, serialization could return a more stripped form such as `(8,,)` for `Node(8)` or `('#',(5,,),)` for `Node('#', Node(5))` and deserialization would be a parser tailored for this representation.

Serialization is easy:

```
    def serialize(self):
        return '({!r},{},{})'.format(
            self.value,
            '' if self.left is None else repr(self.left),
            '' if self.right is None else repr(self.right))
```

Deserialization is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, love your comments and vote up. Is there a solution using BFS (serialize tree layer by layer) other than DFS (or pre-order traverse as we did now) for serialize and de-serialize?

Comment: BTW, also wondering if you have good ideas how store `None` as `#`? Suppose the tree is not very balanced, there will be a lot `#`. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is for Python 3 only. You can have the simplicity of a global variable without actually having a global variable, by using an inner function. You'd have to declare the variable as nonlocal so that the inner function doesn't attempt to create another one.

```
def deserialize(self, data):
    source = data.split(',')
    index = 0

    def helper():
        nonlocal index

        if source[index] == '#':
            index += 1
            return None

        node = TreeNode(int(source[index]))
        index += 1
        node.left, node.right = helper(), helper()
        return node

    return helper()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].